# How do I uncompress or unarchive the contents of initramfs img file in Arch Linux?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, initramfs, mkinitcpio, zstd

I have been using **Arch Linux** for a while and studying about the **initramfs**. I thought of looking into the contents of the file to get a clear idea of it. I googled for various ways to peek through the file but I was not able to.

Initially, I checked the file type of initramfs using the below command and got the following output:

```
file /boot/initramfs-linux.img
/boot/initramfs-linux.img: Zstandard compressed data (v0.8+), Dictionary IS: None
```

I found that the file was **Zstandard compressed** and used the **zstd** tool to fetch the content of the file as follows:

```
zstd -d /boot/initramfs-linux.img -o SOME_FILE_NAME
```

That yielded gibberish result. I gave a file name as it's argument since it complained when I gave a directory.

I thought that the initramfs file contains the initial root file system (set of files and directories).

I am **naive** to Arch Linux and it's internals. Kindly help me through this.

Thanks.

Comment: Run `file` again on the ZSTD output (unpack to a new file). You'll learn something new.

Comment: I did a file again and it's an **ASCII cpio archive**

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [Artem S. Tashkinov](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/260833/artem-s-tashkinov) for guiding.

I did a `file` command on the extracted file. The output was a **ASCII cpio archive**.

Now I used the following command to extract the contents of the cpio archive

```
cpio -idv < FILE_NAME
```

Finally, I could get the contents of initramfs archive.

Comment: The answer as is doesn't work, because initramfs is typically compressed, so you need to uncompress it before passing over to `cpio`. For example for zstd-compressed files that would be `zstd -cd ./initramfs-linux.img | cpio -idv`, which writes the content of initramfs to the current directory *(so be aware of that and better do that in a temporary directory you can easily get rid of later)*